# SQL Server 2016 derived flag into Over Partition

Tags: sql-server

I'm building the capability to distinguish between individual shifts and overlapping shifts.
I need to feed a derived flag back into the Over (Partition By) statement so I can only return the min and max start and end shift time for the overlapping shifts.  The flag returns the overlapping condition when = 1

```
    SELECT [temp_Emp], [temp_EmpID],[temp_Date],[Temp_Start],[Temp_End],
    case    when (Temp_End > Lead(Temp_Start, 1)OVER(ORDER BY temp_EmpID,         temp_Date, Temp_Start, Temp_End ))
        or (Temp_Start < Lag(Temp_End , 1)OVER(ORDER BY temp_EmpID,         temp_Date, Temp_Start, Temp_End))
    then 1  else 0  end as 'Flag',
    case    when (Temp_End > Lead(Temp_Start, 1)OVER(ORDER BY temp_EmpID,         temp_Date, Temp_Start, Temp_End ))
or (Temp_Start < Lag(Temp_End , 1)OVER(ORDER BY temp_EmpID, temp_Date,         Temp_Start, Temp_End))
    then min(Temp_Start) over (partition by temp_EmpID, temp_Date ) 
    else Temp_Start end as 'Start', 
    case when (Temp_End > Lead(Temp_Start, 1)OVER(ORDER BY temp_EmpID,         temp_Date, Temp_Start, Temp_End ))
or (Temp_Start < Lag(Temp_End , 1)OVER(ORDER BY temp_EmpID, temp_Date,         Temp_Start, Temp_End))
    then max(Temp_End) over (partition by temp_EmpID, temp_Date ) 
    else Temp_End   end as 'End'
    FROM tmp_startend;
```

This is the current output:

```
temp_EmpID  Temp_Start  Temp_End  Flag  Start  End
300  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 8:15  0  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 8:15
300 7/08/2017 8:15  7/08/2017 8:30  0  7/08/2017 8:15  7/08/2017 8:30
300  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 10:00  1  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 9:15  7/08/2017 14:30  1  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 9:30  7/08/2017 14:00  1  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 10:00  7/08/2017 12:30  1  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 10:00  7/08/2017 12:30  1  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 10:00  7/08/2017 12:30  1  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 10:00  7/08/2017 13:00  1  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 10:00  7/08/2017 14:30  1  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 14:00  7/08/2017 15:00  1  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 15:00
```

Consider the top 2 rows are not overlapping and I want to exclude them from the Over Partition 
The max column appears to work and shows the correct End time for the overlapping shifts 
However the Start column is returning the minimum across the Over(Partition)
I'm using SQL Server 2016

This is the required output.

```
temp_EmpID  Temp_Start  Temp_End  Flag  Start  End
300  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 8:15  0  7/08/2017 8:00  7/08/2017 8:15
300  7/08/2017 8:15  7/08/2017 8:30  0  7/08/2017 8:15  7/08/2017 8:30
300  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 10:00  1  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 9:15  7/08/2017 14:30  1  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 9:30  7/08/2017 14:00  1  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 10:00  7/08/2017 12:30  1  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 10:00  7/08/2017 12:30  1  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 10:00  7/08/2017 12:30  1  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 10:00  7/08/2017 13:00  1  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 10:00  7/08/2017 14:30  1  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 15:00
300  7/08/2017 14:00  7/08/2017 15:00  1  7/08/2017 9:00  7/08/2017 15:00
```

Comment: please post expected result,actual result and test data as ddl,dml

Comment: check this link to know more on how to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Gameiswar, the ddl is in the question body and I've got the table of the output of the query and I've added a table of the data required.

Comment: Please spend some time to go through the link,ddl goes some thing like this '`create table #t(id int) insert into #t(1),(2)`

Comment: I've gone through the link and yes I'm learning but the question has the ddl, starting with: SELECT [temp_Emp], [temp_EmpID],[temp_Date],

Comment: Could I use a CTE to resolve this?